# Duality for zero-dimensional local Gorenstein algebras

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a finite-dimensional commutative algebra over a field $k$, local with maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$. Then it is well-known that the following are equivalent:

- $A$ has a unique minimal ideal.
- $A$ has one-dimensional socle.
- $A$ is a Frobenius algebra.
- $A$ is Gorenstein.

Then the minimal ideal is given by $\mathfrak{m}^n$ for some $n$, and is equal to the scalar multiples of a fixed element $a \in A$.

All the examples of such algebras that I'm aware of have the following duality property:

> If $x \in \mathfrak{m}^j$ and $x y = 0$ for all $y \in \mathfrak{m}^{n-j}$, then $x \in \mathfrak{m}^{j+1}$.

**Is this true in general under the above assumptions on $A$?**

This seems to be closely related to [Matils duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matlis_duality), but I'm not yet sure about the exact relation. I have also found [literature](https://www.msri.org/~de/papers/pdfs/1996-001.pdf) which states and proves this under the additional assumption that $A$ is graded.

Furthermore, there's a simple induction argument reducing the problem to the following:

> If $y \in A$ is such that $xy \in \mathfrak{m}^{j+1}$ for every $x \in \mathfrak{m}$, then does it follow that $y \in \mathfrak{m}^j$?

This is quite obviously false for local finite-dimensional algebras in general, but again I haven't yet found a counterexample under the above hypotheses.

Comment: I had considered posting this on MO instead, but since I'm sure that this is quite standard and well-known, I want to try here first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a counterexample.  Let $R=k[x,y,z]/(xy,xz,yz,x^3-y^2,x^3-z^2)$. Then $R$ is a finite dimensional local $k$-algebra with maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}=(x,y,z)$ and is Gorenstein. Note $\mathfrak{m}^2=(x^2)$ and the minimal ideal of $R$ is $\mathfrak{m}^3=(x^3)$. Further, $y \in \mathfrak{m}$ satisfies $yx^2=0$, but $y \notin \mathfrak{m}^2$.

The problem with this example is exactly that it is not standard graded, and furthermore the associated graded ring $\operatorname{gr}_{\mathfrak{m}}(R)$ is not Gorenstein.

Comment: That looks like *the* canonical counterexample. Thank you!